# Close application with Ruby

Tags: ruby, command-line

I was wondering how to close my browser from Ruby. I currently know how a way to open by:

```
system('firefox http://www.google.com')
```

How do I close the same browser window?

Comment: I don't get what you mean. I thought the question was straight forward.

Comment: The question is straightforward, but it sounds like a bad idea.  Users will not like it if  you close their browser

Comment: there will be no users. I just need the browser to load a webpage and then close it.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [**Process.spawn**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Process.html#M001282). The usage would be something like this:

```
pid = Process.spawn( "firefox http://www.google.com" )
Process.kill( 'QUIT', pid )
```

Comment: This will kill every open Firefox window.

Comment: Not only does Process.spawn only exist on Ruby1.9, it doesn't necessarily do what the poster needs. When you launch firefox to open a window in an existing session (that is, when there is already a firefox process), the process you launch goes away almost instantly, so the pid you have is useless. The Process.kill() call here will fail with an Errno::ESRCH.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are just trying to "ping" http://www.google.com by opening a browser and then closing it up.

There are faster, easier ways to do that. The simplest one in your case (since you already have a command line set up) would be using **curl** or **wget**:

```
system('wget http://www.google.com')
```

This will "ping" the website, and simply discard the output. It'll be much faster than creating a firefox instance.